# getting to ember.js model enumerable property childs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to get to my models data from a view *didInsertElement* hook, because **I need to trigger some actions on the DOM when the template rendering is completed**.

with models like:

```
App.MyParent = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    childs: DS.hasMany('App.MyChild')
});

App.MyChild = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    parent: DS.belongsTo('App.MyParent')
});
```

and objects like:

```
App.MyParent.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 0, title: "some title", childs: [0,2,3] }
]

App.MyChild.FIXTURES = [
    { id: 0, name: "some name", parent: 0 },
    { id: 2, name: "other name", parent: 0 },
    { id: 3, name: "diff name", parent: 0 }
]
```

Inside the hook function I am getting to the *childs* property like this:

```
var childs = this.get("context.content.childs");
```

then I get an enumerable with the right number of childs, but the child all have *undefined* properties.

**update**
Seems like the only place where I can get to a child with *App.MyChild.find(someId)* is in the browser console, in my app code I only get objects with *undefined* properties.

I'm puzzled!

Answer (score 1):

To access the childs property, try something like this:

```
var childs = this.get("context.content.childs");
```

Also, the fixture data for associations should not use _id or _ids. So use `childs` and `parent` instead:

```
App.MyParent.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 0, title: "some title", childs: [0,2,3] },
];

App.MyChild.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 0, name: "some name", parent: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "other name", parent: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: "diff name", parent: 0 },
];
```

http://jsbin.com/ucanam/316/

Comment: from what I understand, it is the same as:  var childs = this.get("context.content").('childs'); , anyway I get the same results...

Comment: Maybe you mean `this.get("context.content").get('childs');`? In that case yeah it's the same. I think issue is actually with the fixtures, updating my answer...

Comment: I was already noting that using _childs_ instead of _child_ids_, would yield an enumerable result, from which elements: `child.get('name')` yields undefined.  So if using _childs_ instead of _child_ids_ is the right way to do it, what is still wrong with my child objects?

Comment: introspecting a bit more, I can confirm that `child.serialize()`yields an object with undefined properties.

Comment: Problem is not just __childs__ instead of __child_ids__, it's also __parent__ instead of __parent_ids__ - naming conventions need to be right on both sides of the relationship. This jsbin has a working example: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/316/edit

Comment: there must be something else, I was not clear but I implied I understood the **parent** vs **parent_id** earlier.  I'll try my code in _jsbin.com_ and see...  if it works in there and not in my setup it could point to a library version/conflict problem, maybe.

Comment: there is something and I must be too green with ember to see it as my prototype code also bugs in [http://jsbin.com/ozosig/2/edit](http://jsbin.com/ozosig/2/edit)

Comment: The prototype code is trying to access your models from didInsertElement hook. That hook is run before run loop is completed. So bindings have not resolved and content of the models is incomplete.  That's why it seems ok from console - by that time the model data is available. I've made an updated fiddle that outputs the metric data via handlebars template, so you can see that it is there: http://jsbin.com/ovakem/1/edit

Comment: That goes around a central part of this question, that is to get to the models data from a _js_ hook that is triggered once the view has finished rendering. I know from the start that I can get to the models data from inside the templates.  So maybe _didInsertElement_ is not the right hook?  As a sidenote, how can *App.MyParent* be binded and not *App.MyChild* while both have already been used in rendering the template?

Comment: It rarely makes sense to "get to the model's data" instead it is better to "bind to model properties". That's why template works and console.log does not. Template renders while model is incomplete, but bindings update fast so it appears to be instant. If you do need to access model data instead of bind, for sure didInsertElement is not the proper hook. Instead observe one of the lifecycle hooks on your model, see: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/

Comment: there are a couple of short circuiting wires over here: yes templates works but console.log (on the browser) does too, alsoI don't think the models lifecycle will be of any help, it is the view/template cycles I am interested in, unless I could subscribe to _didLoad_ from the _didInsertElement_ hook, but that doesn't seem to get me anywhere.  Where would you use those lifecycle events for them to be useful in this case?

Comment: templates work because they are `binding` to model data. console.log from console works because by the time you have typed it the data is loaded. console.log from didInsertElement hook fails because model data is not available when the hook runs. For sure you could subscribe to didLoad from didInsertElement hook. Agreed not sure where that (or any of this) gets you. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm using a _js_ lib that acts on rendered DOM elements and I want to initiate this lib to some of my models data.

Comment: k. Suggest opening another question, include jsFiddle or code sample, with the js lib if possible.

Comment: For now I went around the problem by having a method on the model that fetches the objects from the fixtures directly, as the fixtures are my only dataset for this model.  I'll leave the question open as it is now because I think it is pretty clear what I want to do, and somebody else might just know the answer.